# Recursive implementation of a singly linked list class in python

Tags: python, algorithm, class, recursion

Sometime ago I decided to learn algorithms but doing it on my own is not easy task, so I'm in the middle of reading a book *Data Structures and Algorithms in Python* by Goodrich but I'm stuck on exercise C-7.27

> Give a recursive implementation of a singly linked list class, such that an instance of a nonempty list stores its first element and a reference to a list of remaining elements. Hint: View the chain of nodes following the head node as themselves forming another list.

I did recursions before with functions but on class level it is a little bit to abstract for me.
I have this base structure and I don't know how to carry on.

```
class SinglyLinkedList:
    '''A base class providing a single linked list representation'''

    class _Node:
        """non public class for storing a singly linked node"""
        __slots__ = '_element', '_next'  # streamline memory usage

        def __init__(self, element, next_el):
            self._element = element
            self._next = next_el

    def __init__(self):
        self._header = self._Node(None, None)
        self._header._next = self._header
        self._size = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self._size

    def is_empty(self):
        return self._size == 0
```

As I understand `_Node._next` should carry `SinglyLinkedList` class something like this:

```
def append(self, e):
    newest = _Node(e, SinglyLinkedList())
```

But now to dress it up in recursion so I can picture it as a whole. Can any help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: in a singly linked list the last node should not link to anything; use `None` to indicate the end of a list. In your code the last node links back to itself.

Recursion using instances just means that you'll call the same method still, but on another instance rather than use a global function or the same method on `self`.

For appending to a linked list then, you'd call `append()` on the next node, and the recursion termination condition is handling appending at the node that has *no next node* (e.g. the end of the list):

```
class _Node:
    """non public class for storing a singly linked node"""
    __slots__ = '_element', '_next'  # streamline memory usage

    def __init__(self, element, next_el):
        self._element = element
        self._next = next_el

    def append(self, element):
        if self._next is not None:
            self._next.append(element)
        self._next = SinglyLinkedList._Node(element, None)
```

You'll need to add a `append()` method to the `SinglyLinkedList` class too that kicks off the recursion, and adjusts the length.

You'll want to start with `self._head = None` in `SinglyLinkedList.__init__` for an empty list, by the way. Handle that case when appending; empty list -> create first node, non-empty -> recurse:

```
def append(self, element):
    if self._head is None:
        self._head = self._Node(element, None)
    else:
        self._head.append(element)
    self._size += 1
```

Note that you don't have to 'nest' `_Node` inside the `SinglyLinkedList` class; it only makes referencing the class harder hear for your own code. I had to use `SinglyLinkedList._Node()` inside `_Node.append()` to reference the class; the alternative would be to use `type(self)()`.

Comment: Thanks Martjin. it helped now I need some time to get the grip with this concepts. cheers